# Using @Cacheable annotation with a Reactive controller method

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, redis, spring-cache

I am currently trying to implement a caching with Redis for Sprint Boot application:

```
@Cacheable(value = "products", key = "#id")
@GetMapping(value = "/product/{id}")
public Mono<Product> getProduct(@PathVariable("id") String sku) {
    ...
}
```

However, I am encountering this exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: DefaultSerializer requires a Serializable payload but received an object of type [reactor.core.publisher.MonoMapFuseable]
```

Based on my research, this has to do with it trying to serialize the Mono return type, rather than `Product` itself. So my question is, for reactive methods such as this, what is the recommended way of implementing a caching mechanism with Redis? Comments and feedback would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change return type of getProduct() from **Mono** to **Product**.

Since you are getting only one product at a time, and you are using Mono<> because it emits at most one item and then (optionally) terminates with an onComplete signal or an onError signal.

so instead of that use Product as return type and define if else for no product i.e, at error state.

Or else
go through these links for ways of implementing a caching mechanism with Redis

- https://www.devglan.com/spring-boot/spring-boot-redis-cache
- https://dzone.com/articles/implementation-of-redis-in-micro-servicespring-boo

Comment: Thanks, I ended up implementing a Provider for Redis.

Comment: hey @kayelbb, mind to elaborate on that Provider thing? currently struggling with the same redis-reactive-cacheable issue